# Ruby classArray[index].class_method is not working in different scope

Tags: arrays, ruby, class

The goal of the program is to read in the file and output: 
1. A list of each student with the full course name(s) for which they are enrolled.
2. A list of each course with the full list of student name(s) enrolled in that course.

I got stuck with the first problem so I haven't started working on the second one yet. Line 151 and line 118 have exact(except the index) expression but line 151 doesn't have the same output to the screen as 118, so I am wondering whether it's caused by class array studentArray's scope.

Also, I don't know how to write the set and get functions for a private variable whose type is an array in a class. In this case, how to write set and get functions for courselist in class Student?

ruby version: 2.3.7 (on Mac)

Input file:

```
A12345  Joseph P. Allen, Jr.
A23456  Brenda Gomez
A34567  Stephanie McGraw

987 CS 424  Programming Languages
123 CS 490  Operating Systems
456 CS 317  Algorithms

A12345  987
A34567  123
A23456  456
A12345  123
```

My code file:

```
class Student
    # constructor
    def initialize(name, number, courselist)
        @@sName, @@sNumber = name, number
        @@sCourselist = courselist
    end

    #gets
    def getStudentName
        @@sName
    end
    def getStudentNumber
        @@sNumber
    end
    def getCourselist
        @@sCourselist
    end

    #sets
    def setStudentName(name)
        @@sName = name
    end
    def setStudentNumber(number)
        @@sNumber = number
    end
    def setCourselist(course)
        @@sCourselist = course
    end
end

class Course
    #constructor
    def initialize(name, number, enrolllist)
        @cName, @cNumber = name, number
        @cEnrolllist = enrolllist
    end

    # gets
    def getCourseName
        @cName
    end
    def getCourseNumber
        @cNumber
    end
    def getEnrolllist
        @cEnrolllist
    end

    #sets
    def setCourseName(name)
        @cName = name
    end
    def setCourseNumber(number)
        @cNumber = number
    end
end

=begin
 class Enrollment
 #constructor
 def initialize(studentNumber, courseNumber)
 @eStudentNumber, @eCourseNumber = studentNumber, courseNumber
 end
 # gets
 def getCourseNumber
 @eCourseNumber
 end
 def getStudentNumber
 @eStudentNumber
 end
 #sets
 def setStudentNumber(number)
 @eStudentNumber = number
 end
 def setCourseNumber(number)
 @eCourseNumber = number
 end
 end
=end


def from(position)
    self[position..-1]
end

def to(position)
    self[0..position]
end

studentCount, courseCount = -1, -1

#open file to read
file = File.read("register.txt")

student = Student.new("", "", "")
course = Course.new("", "", "")

studentArray = Array.new
courseArray = Array.new

file = File.readlines("register.txt")
num = 0
for i in 0..file.length-1
    if num == 0
        puts "This is part1"
        number = file[i].split("\t", 2)[0]
        name = file[i].split("\t", 2)[1]

        student.setStudentName(name)
        student.setStudentNumber(number)

        puts student.getStudentNumber
        puts student.getStudentName

        studentArray.insert(i, student)

        puts "Student number in Part1:"
        puts studentArray[i].getStudentNumber

        studentCount = studentCount + 1
    end

    if num == 1
        puts "This is part2"
        number = file[i].split(" ", 2)[0]
        name = file[i].split(" ", 2)[1]

        course.setCourseName(name)
        course.setCourseNumber(number)

        puts course.getCourseNumber
        puts course.getCourseName

        courseArray.push(course)

        courseCount = courseCount + 1
    end

    if num == 2
        puts "This is part3"
        student = file[i].split(" ", 2)[0]
        puts student
        course = file[i].split(" ", 2)[1]
        puts course

        #for j in 0..studentCount-1

        #puts studentArray[j].setCourselist(course)
        #puts j
        puts "Student number in Part3:"
        puts studentArray[0].getStudentNumber
        #puts studentArray[j]
=begin
         if studentArray[j].getStudentNumber == student
         student.setCourselist(course)
         end
=end
        #end
        #puts student.getCourselist

    end

    if(file[i].start_with?"\n")
        num = num + 1
    end

end
```

There's no error returned for line 151 in the terminal but just no output on the screen. The reason why I have private variables in class Student as @@variable and @variable in a class Course is that I am not sure which one to use and whether this is causing the problem.

Comment: This code is really confusing. Why are you using class variables (`@@`) inside your instances? Is this intentional? Those are shared amongst all instances of that class. `@` instance variables are *per instance* which is probably what you want.

Comment: Note: Ruby is a case-sensitive language and capital letters have specific meaning in terms of syntax. Variables and method names should be lower-case letters. Capitals indicate constants of the form  `ClassName` or `CONSTANT_NAME`.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible what you're missing here is that Ruby really doesn't make use of conventional (e.g. Java or C++-style) getter/setter methods. Instead you can use `attr_reader`/`attr_writer` to declare them, or `attr_accessor` for read/write access. This idiomatic approach is often way less code.

For example, your Student class boils down to this:

```
class Student
  attr_accessor :name, :number, :courselist

  def initialize(name, number, courselist)
    @name = name
    @number = number
    @courselist = courselist
  end
end
```

Now you can call:

```
student = Student.new('Jerome', 23, [ 'Course A' ])
student.name # => 'Jerome'
student.name = 'Jasmine'
student.name # => 'Jasmine'
```

Where the `name` and `name=` methods handle read and write access respectively.

Another problem you have is that you're recycling the same objects repeatedly and inserting multiple copies of the same thing in an array. This is a huge problem, but there's an easy fix: create a new instance each time, never recycle it. When you insert something into an array you insert an *object reference*, not a copy. In other words:

```
array = [ ]
student = Student.new('Billy', 2, [ ])
array << student
student.name = 'Barlow'
array << student
```

This is the *exact same* Student object being pushed into the array twice. Now you have two students named "Barlow" and zero named "Billy". To find out why:

```
array.map(&:object_id)
```

This shows you the object identifier values, or the low-level ID of the object, which is distinct for each individual object but identical for precisely the same object showing up somewhere more than once.

Instead create a new record as necessary. If you want to start with an empty record and populate it, make your classes more lax. For example:

```
class Student
  def initialize(name: nil, number: nil, courselist: [ ])
    @name = name
    @number = number
    @courselist = courselist
  end
end
```

Where now there's *named keyword arguments* that you call like:

```
student = Student.new(name: 'Stella')
```

You don't have to specify all parameters, they have defaults, plus as a bonus you can specify them in any order you want.

Now for your parsing loop:

```
 loop do
   # Make a new Student record each time
   student = Student.new

   # ... Populate student with mutator methods like student.name = '...'

   array << student
 end
```

Whenever possible use something like `map` to convert from one array (e.g. list of lines) into another of the same size with different content (e.g. Student records). This avoids a lot of issues with recycling variables, incrementing counters, and having to `push` in the proper place. It's a 1:1 mapping/transformation and very powerful.

Architect your code into a series of simpler transformations, like:

1. Split the input up into three different sections by scanning for the appropriate breaks.
2. Transform each section into the appropriate record type using `map`.
3. Link the data together by using look-up tables (e.g. Hash) if necessary. You can quickly index an array by a key using Rails with [`index_by`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-index_by), though doing that without the helper is just a few more lines of code.

Comment: I'm glad to see that you took a completely different tack than I did: how to organize the information as opposed to how to extract the needed information from the data at hand. I suggest you show a courses class as well (with attributes id and name, say), make @courselist an array of course instances, and add a method that compiles a list of student instances per course (which is asked for by the question).

Answer (score 3):

You really should be using a database for this or, at minimum, confine each of the three types of data (students, courses and student assignments to courses) to its own file, possibly a [CSV](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) file. Nevertheless, here is how you can proceed with what you have.

Let's first put your data into a file named `"test"`<sup>1</sup>.

```
data =<<END
A12345  Joseph P. Allen, Jr.
A23456  Brenda Gomez
A34567  Stephanie McGraw

987 CS 424  Programming Languages
123 CS 490  Operating Systems
456 CS 317  Algorithms

A12345  987
A34567  123
A23456  456
A12345  123
END

FName = 'test'
IO.write(FName, data)
  #=> 212
```

As you see, 212 characters were written to file. See [IO::write](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/IO.html#method-c-write). Now let's read the file and break it into three strings, to be held by variables `students`, `courses`, `assignments` (See [IO::read](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/IO.html#method-c-read).)

```
student_str, course_str, assignment_str = File.read(FName).split(/\n{2,}/)
student_str
  #=> "A12345  Joseph P. Allen, Jr.\nA23456  Brenda Gomez\nA34567  Stephanie McGraw"     
course_str
  #=> "987 CS 424  Programming Languages\n123 CS 490  Operating Systems\n456 CS 317  Algorithms" 
assignment_str
  #=> "A12345  987\nA34567  123\nA23456  456\nA12345  123\n"
```

Note that I split the string on two or more consecutive line breaks (`\n`), `/\n{2,}/` being a *regular expression*.

We will need to break each of these three strings into lines and then break each line  into two pieces. In `students`, for example, the first line is `"A12345  Joseph P. Allen, Jr.\n"`. We need to break this into the student's id, `"A12345"` and name, `"Joseph P. Allen, Jr.\n"`. We can do that with the following method:

```
def divide_str(s)
  s.chomp.split(/\s+/, 2)
end

divide_str("A12345  Joseph P. Allen, Jr.\n")
  #=> ["A12345", "Joseph P. Allen, Jr."]
```

This uses the form of the method [String#split](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-split) that makes use of an optional second argument, the maximum number of pieces into which the spring is to be split.

We need to be able to manipulate students by their ids, but also to convert ids to names, when necessary. The latter calls for a hash, which we may constuct with the following method:

```
def str_to_hash(s)
  s.lines.map { |s| divide_str(s) }.to_h
end
```

Let's first apply that to students:

```
students_to_names = str_to_hash(student_str)
  #=> {"A12345"=>"Joseph P. Allen, Jr.", "A23456"=>"Brenda Gomez",
  #    "A34567"=>"Stephanie McGraw"}
```

The two steps here are as follows:

```
arr = student_str.lines.map { |s| divide_str(s) }
  #=> [["A12345", "Joseph P. Allen, Jr."], ["A23456", "Brenda Gomez"],
  #    ["A34567", "Stephanie McGraw"]]
```

Then `arr.to_h` produces the hash shown above. See [Array#to_h](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-to_h).

From this hash construct a list of students (ids):

```
students = students_to_names.keys
  #=> ["A12345", "A23456", "A34567"]
```

Now do the same for courses.

```
courses_to_names = str_to_hash(course_str)
  #=> {"987"=>"CS 424  Programming Languages", "123"=>"CS 490  Operating Systems",
  #    "456"=>"CS 317  Algorithms"} 
courses = courses_to_names.keys
  #=> ["987", "123", "456"]
```

Next, construct a list of student/course pairs:

```
student_course_pairs = assignment_str.lines.map { |s| divide_str(s) }
  #=> [["A12345", "987"], ["A34567", "123"], ["A23456", "456"], ["A12345", "123"]]
```

We are now ready to obtain the list of courses each student will take and the list of students that will be in each course. Again, hashes are the appropriate Ruby object for this information. In one of these hashes the keys are student ids and values are arrays of course ids. In the other the keys are course ids and the values are arrays of student ids. All of these arrays are initially empty:

```
courses_by_student = students.map { |s| [s, []] }.to_h
  #=> {"A12345"=>[], "A23456"=>[], "A34567"=>[]} 

students_by_course = courses.map { |s| [s, []] }.to_h
  #=> {"987"=>[], "123"=>[], "456"=>[]}
```

We will now step through `student_course_pairs` to fill these arrays:

```
student_course_pairs.each do |student, course|
  courses_by_student[student] << course
  students_by_course[course]  << student
end
```

Let's see what we have:

```
courses_by_student
  #=> {"A12345"=>["987", "123"], "A23456"=>["456"], "A34567"=>["123"]} 
students_by_course
  #=> {"987"=>["A12345"], "123"=>["A34567", "A12345"], "456"=>["A23456"]}
```

By having constructed the hashes `students_to_names` and `courses_to_names` we can easily supply information in whatever form is desired. For example, if we want a list of the names of students enrolled in each course, we could perform the following simple manipulation:

```
student_names_by_course = students_by_course.transform_values do |a|
  a.map { |student| students_to_names[student] }
end
  #=> {"987"=>["Joseph P. Allen, Jr."],
  #    "123"=>["Stephanie McGraw", "Joseph P. Allen, Jr."],
  #    "456"=>["Brenda Gomez"]}
```

<sup>1. The variable `data` is set equal to a string defined by a [Here Document](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html), or "heredoc". (Search for "here document" in the linked file.)</sup>